# Surface integral of $z=x^2+y^2$ when enclosed by $z=2$ and $z=6$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to take the surface integral of

$$z=x^2+y^2$$

inside the region defined by $z=2$ and $z=6$

It can be proven that this is the same as integrating:

$$\int\int_K\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2}\ dydx =$$

$$\int\int_K\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}\ dydx $$

over the region $K$ which is the $2$ circumferences defined by the planes, which have equation in polar coordinates:

$$p=\sqrt{2}\\p=\sqrt{6} \\0\le\theta\le 2\pi$$

So converting the integral to polar coordinates by making $x=p\cos\theta, y=p\sin\theta$ I have:

$$\frac{1}{8}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{6}}\sqrt{1+4p^2}\ 8p \ dpd\theta $$

[which is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F8%20integrate%20%28integrate%20sqrt%281%2B4p%5E2%298p%20dp%20from%20sqrt%282%29%20to%20sqrt%286%29%29dt%20from%200%20to%202pi) $$\frac{49\pi}{3}$$

but my book says $\frac{13\pi}{3}$

What am I doing wrong? How can I numeric evaluate surface areas like this to compare to my integrals?

Comment: The area of a cylinder of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and length $4$ has to be less than the area of the surface of revolution you are trying to compute, yet that area is $2\pi \sqrt{2}\cdot 4\approx 11.3\pi$, much more than $13\pi/3$.

Comment: By "surface integral of" do you mean "surface area of"?

Comment: @ForgotALot so my answer is 'more correct'? I'm thinking the answer is wrong, it's not really a book...

Comment: As best I can tell, either your book is wrong, or you have misunderstood what your book is asking you to compute.

Comment: @ForgotALot if what the book is telling me to compute is what I have written here, I'm doing it rigth, right?

Comment: I think so, but given the doubt I have as to why that strange $13\pi/3$ is there, I have not checked it to the last detail.

Comment: You can't compute the surface integral of a 2d surface.  It is a nonsensical request.  You can compute surface area of a 2d surface, or you can compute the surface area of a function over the region of a 2d surface, but it doesn't mean anything to compute the surface integral of a 2d surface.